# How can I Numeric values written like this 20190101123411 into date format in R?

Tags: r

i have date and time written like this `"20190101123411"`. which comprise year, month, date, hour, minutes, seconds consecutively. how can change into date format in R Studio

```
x<-20190101123411
datetime<-as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x) origin=2019-01-01 12:34:11)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `format` to specify the format of your date-time (after converting to character):

```r
as.POSIXct(as.character(x), format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
#[1] "2019-01-01 12:34:11 CET"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

ymd_hms(x)
[1] "2019-01-01 12:34:11 UTC"
```